# Warning in rails server - localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In any tutorials about rails, its possible see a lot informations in server console, but, for me just warnings.

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 
2013-09-26 12:24:10 -0300
[2013-09-26 12:24:10] WARN  Could not determine content-length of 
response body. Set content-length of the response or set 
Response#chunked = true
```

I don't know why.

Also, when I try to run something style `puts "Hello world"`, It is not displayed on the server console.

I'm new in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server and the console operate independently, as separate applications.  So if you fire up a console with `rails c`, it will be a standalone build of your application.  Similarly, if you do `rails s`, it will also be standalone.

The exception is that they both share your development database, so if you make changes to the database with the console, they will be reflected on a page refresh of your server.  Vice versa is also true.

Don't worry about the warnings for content length on the server, they don't affect anything.

**EDIT**

For debugging purposes, you can write custom items to the log, or you can display items such as params, etc in the view layer.  More info on that here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Right, but, how can I show some information in rails server console/log, with my application? It's possible? or for that I need use logger in a file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "server console".  The server and the console are two different things.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean "Server log": the return of server log (when I execute rails server, in each requisition the server show some informations right? I talk about that).

Comment: Got it. Sounds like you're using it for debugging purposes.  I'll edit  my answer to include some resources for that.